# Divide Value from one Dataframe by Value of another Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grouping

these are my two dataframes:

```
    structure(list(Full.Name = c("A. Patrick Beharelle", "A. Patrick Beharelle", 
"Aaron P. Graft", "Aaron P. Graft", "Aaron P. Jagdfeld"), year = c(2019, 
2020, 2019, 2020, 2019), counter = c(5541L, 3269L, 165L, 200L, 
4L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), groups = structure(list(Full.Name = c("A. Patrick Beharelle", 
"Aaron P. Graft", "Aaron P. Jagdfeld"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:2, 3:4, 5L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

and

```
structure(list(authority_dic = c("accomplished", "accomplished", 
"accomplished", "accomplished", "accomplished"), Full.Name = c("A. Patrick Beharelle", "A. Patrick Beharelle", 
"Aaron P. Graft", "Aaron P. Graft", "Aaron P. Jagdfeld"), Entity = c("WERNER ENTERPRISES INC", "MONDELEZ INTERNATIONAL INC", 
"AEROJET ROCKETDYNE HOLDINGS", "T-MOBILE US INC", "SOUTHWEST AIRLINES"
), `2019` = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `2020` = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 
1L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), groups = structure(list(authority_dic = c("accomplished", 
"accomplished", "accomplished", "accomplished", "accomplished"
), Full.Name = c("Derek J. Leathers", "Dirk Van de Put", "Eileen P. Drake", 
"G. Michael Sievert", "Gary C. Kelly"), .rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Now, I want to divide each value of the "2019" column by the "counter" value of the other dataframe and add the result as another column. The complexity comes in place, because I only want to divide through the "counter" value of 2019 and of (for example) Aaron P. Graft.
I want to do this for every row of the dataframe containing the name "Aaron P. Graft" and therefore take the value of "counter" from the other dataframe in the row, which contains "Aaron P. Graft".

I cannot figure it out on my own. Maybe I need to transpose the year and counter columns in the first dataframe, but I don't know.

Thats what I want to achieve:

| authority_dic | Full.name | 2019 | 2020 | 2019_freq | 2020_freq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| example word | Aaron P. Jagdfeld | 10 | 20 | 10/counter(of 2019) | 20/counter(of 2020) |

If there are any questions, don't mind asking me.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I suggest you start by pivoting (wide-to-long) the second table so that your "year" columns is in a single `year` column; from there, join/merge the two and do a conditional calc (i.e., `ifelse` or similar).

Comment: Where do your `10` and `20` values come from?

Comment: 10 and 20 are just random values for illustration purposes. Sorry, if it caused confusion.

Comment: the idea of pivoting sounds good! but I would only have to pivot a certain part of the dataframe and I am not sure on how to do so. If you know how to, I'd really appreciate it. :) Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the structures be `s1` and `s2`, this should work:

```
library(tidyr)
mutate(
      full_join(
         summarise(
            group_by(s2, authority_dic, Full.Name),
            `2019`=sum(`2019`),
            `2020`=sum(`2020`)),
         s1 %>% spread(year,counter),
         by=c("Full.Name")),
      `2019_freq`=`2019.x`/`2019.y`,
      `2020_freq`=`2020.x`/`2020.y`)
# A tibble: 3 × 8
# Groups:   authority_dic [1]
  authority_dic Full.Name            `2019.x` `2020.x` `2019.y` `2020.y` `2019_freq` `2020_freq`
  <chr>         <chr>                   <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 accomplished  A. Patrick Beharelle        1        1     5541     3269    0.000180    0.000306
2 accomplished  Aaron P. Graft              1        3      165      200    0.00606     0.015   
3 accomplished  Aaron P. Jagdfeld           0        1        4       NA    0          NA
```

Good practice is to avoid naming columns with values, e.g. 2019.... Use `year` instead. Your model needs refactoring into normal form (see database normalization topic for more information).

Comment: Thank you so much! It works just fine. I know the naming of the columns is a little awkward, so thank you for your help! I appreciate it.